# Static methods not inherited?

Tags: inheritance, static-methods, haxe

I'm in the process of learning Haxe, which, so far, seems to be a pretty nifty language. However, I'm confused by the following. Although [the documentation](http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-inheritance.html) doesn't mention anything explicitly, the following causes a compiler error:

```
class HasMethod {
    public static function doSomething() {
        trace("Hello World");
    }
}

class Extender extends HasMethod {}

class HelloWorld {
    public static function main () {
        HasMethod.doSomething();
        Extender.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Namely, it complains that:

```
HelloWorld.hx:12: characters 2-22 : Class<Extender> has no field doSomething
```

I take it to mean that static methods just aren't inherited? Is there a reason for this? Is it a limitation of (one of) the underlying playforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fair to assume this is a design choice, and a wise one.

Inheritance is a mechanism for objects to override certain behaviors.

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Animal b = new Cat();
// a and b, although both animals, they will behave differently
```

What would be the point of static inheritance? The functions are static, they belong directly to the class. Hence there is no instanciation, no polymorphism, and "inheriting" static functions makes little sense in that context.

Answer (score 3):

A method that is declared static is called a class method. When you use inheritance you create objects that their class is derived from another class (which is why you can use methods of the parent which were not declared as `private`). In other words - the rules of inheritance apply for the objects that were instantiated from the derived class.

The class itself is NOT such an object which explains why you can't call `Extender.doSomething();`